# Styled-components use function in styled object

Tags: javascript, css, styled-components, css-in-js

Could not find a clear example how to use functions in css objects with `styled-components`. It's not throwing an error, but background is not added to the CSS output when extracting props like in the example below.

```
// Simple color function
const color = (error) => {
 if (error) {
   return 'red'
 }
 return 'black',
}
```

**Works** - css

```
const StyledInput = styled.input<InputProps>`
  background: ${({ error }) => color(error)};`;
```

**Working** - css object

```
const StyledInput = styled.input<InputProps>(props => ({
  background: color(), // !!! NEED error from props
}));
```

**Not working** - css object

```
const StyledInput = styled.input<InputProps>(props => ({
  background: `${({ error }) => color(error)}`,
}));
```

Comment: If you have 2 working methods, why not use those? I am confused... Do you mean none of them are actually working, contrary to what you stated `Works`, `Working`, etc.

Comment: Sorry, the working example cannot take arguments! `error` is not set, I need to destruct it from props.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve the props extract issue you should be able to do this:

```
// Simple color function
const color = (error) => {
  if (error) {
    return 'red';
  }
  return 'black';
};

const StyledInput = styled.input<InputProps>(({ error, ...props }) => ({
  background: color(error),
}));
```

Comment: And what, if I want to add a couple of arguments, not only 'error', let's say `value`, `error` and `disabled`.

Comment: Only thing right now is that we need to destruct the keys from props which we would like to pass. It would be a better approach when we could destruct the properties we need for the function we need them for.